# Define Procedures inside Packages

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created some Procedures in SQL Developer, and they are working fine. However I am now creating a Package to include all those Procedures, and can't seem to figure out the right way to code the Package as it returns the following error (refering to the PACKAGE BODY's CREATE):

```
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"
```

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE package_test AS

PROCEDURE copy_object;

END package_test;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY package_test AS

PROCEDURE copy_object IS
CURSOR object_cursor IS
SELECT COD_OBJECT, OBJECT_NAME FROM OBJECT;

object_rec object_cursor%rowtype;

BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE2.D_OBJECT';
FOR object_rec IN object_cursor
LOOP
    INSERT INTO DATABASE2.D_OBJECT (COD_OBJECT,OBJECT_NAME) VALUES (object_rec.OOD_OBJECT,object_rec.OBJECT_NAME);
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END copy_object;
END package_test;
```

I have done some searching and the only thing I can think of is maybe some problem related to the definition on the CURSOR...not sure though. Thanks in advance

Comment: Put a "/" on a separate line after "END package_test;" (and after the body creation) if you intend to run it as a script. This will execute the previous command (the create command) where as the semi-colon is just separating statements.

Comment: You are also missing a "T" on "INSER" and have a comma after "COMMIT" instead of a semi-colon.

Comment: I had already tried that and the error changes to "Encountered the symbol"/" ". Also I read in Oreilly's "Oracle PL/SQL Programming" that "/" was only part of SQLPlus and I am using SQL Developer. @Glenn that was because I didnt use copy paste, because it was in another computer without Internet so I manually copied it :P

Comment: In sqldeveloper, you have two options "run statement" (green arrow) and "run script" (green arrow over a page). If you use run script, use the slash. It works. If you want to run statement, then just select one statement at a time. For example select the package spec statement and run that. Then select the package body statement and run that. In that case you won't need the slash.

Comment: But given that the code is not compiled right (even with the "/") I can't run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully ran this in sqlplus and sqldeveloper (F5 in sqldeveloper: "Run Script"). I changed the two dml statements since my schema is different.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE package_test AS
  2
  3  PROCEDURE copy_object;
  4
  5  END package_test;
  6  /

Package created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY package_test AS
  2
  3  PROCEDURE copy_object IS
  4  CURSOR object_cursor IS
  5  SELECT * from dual;
  6
  7  object_rec object_cursor%rowtype;
  8
  9  BEGIN
 10  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE2.D_OBJECT';
 11  FOR object_rec IN object_cursor
 12  LOOP
 13      NULL; --INSER INTO DATABASE2.D_OBJECT (COD_OBJECT,OBJECT_NAME) VALUES (object_rec.OOD_OBJECT,object_rec.OBJECT_
NAME);
 14  END LOOP;
 15  COMMIT;
 16  END copy_object;
 17  END package_test;
 18  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes it runs I successfully compiled and run it too, I think it was a blank space ;) Thank you!